# What registry values are modified by the Ruby and Ruby on Rails Windows installer?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, windows, windows-installer

I am using Windows 7 and Windows 2008 Server. I used the Ruby and Ruby on Rails one-click installer. What registry keys does the installer modify and create? Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It depends on the checkboxes you have selected.

Everything is in the source of the installer itself.

1. Either `SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Session Manager\Environment` (Admin) or `Environment` (normal user), inside that `PATH` and `PATHEXT`. [Source](https://github.com/oneclick/rubyinstaller/blob/master/resources/installer/util.iss#L31-47)
2. `Software\Classes` for `.rb`, `.rbw` and both `RubyFile` and `RubyFileW` either HKLM or HKCU. [Source](https://github.com/oneclick/rubyinstaller/blob/master/resources/installer/rubyinstaller.iss#L124-147)
3. Inside `Software` to identify the installer version, patchlevel and other information. Either HKLM (Admin) or HKCU (normal user). [Source](https://github.com/oneclick/rubyinstaller/blob/master/resources/installer/rubyinstaller.iss#L149-165)

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

If looking at the source is not enough (see Lous Lavenas answer) then you might take a look at [Process Monitor](http://technet.microsoft.com/de-de/sysinternals/bb896645).  It allows you to monitor all registry related activites of a process.

Just start Process Monitor, add a filter for the installer, so you don't get spammed with registry actions from other processes, and run the installer.